# JavaFX Filter TableView when method is in another class

Tags: java, uitableview, javafx

I'm sorry if this is really simple question for you all, but I am having trouble. I am trying to accomplish a JavaFX application, and I am nearly done.

I am having trouble filtering a TableView. I have a TextField as my search input and a button to act as my "Submit" button to search. I am aware of event listeners and what not for TextFields to filter a TableView. I am not opposed to that option, but, I need button functionality.

I have a MainController class for my main stage, and that is where I house two TableViews and the search input field / button.

Now, the method is called "lookupProduct(int id)" but, it is in another class: Inventory

So, my question is, how can I make a call from the MainController to the method in the Inventory class, and filter the TableView that way? I'm sorry. I cannot post code, but I can provide as good an example as possible.

ContainsMethod.java

```
private MainController mainController;
.....

void lookUpProduct(int id){
    FilteredList<Product> filteredList = new FilteredList<Product>(maincontroller.productsTableView.getItems());
    filteredList.stream()

            .filter(item -> item.getName() == name)
            .findAny()
            .ifPresent(item -> {
                maincontroller.productsTableView.getSelectionModel().select(item);
                maincontroller.productsTableView.scrollTo(item);
            });
    maincontroller.productsTableView.setItems(filteredList);
}
```

MainController.java

```
@FXML
private void handleLookupProduct(ActionEvent event) {
    Inventory inv = new Inventory();
    String searchText = productsSearchInput.getText();
    if (searchText.length() != 0) {
        inv.lookupProduct(searchText);
    } else {
        AlertBox.display("WAIT!", "Please enter a value to search!", 450);
    }
}
```

Any assistance, guidance, suggestions you can provide, will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you just move `lookUpProduct` to the `MainController`? It looks like everything it needs is in `MainController` anyway.

Comment: I am assuming you don't have an instance variable of `MainController`, and thats why it is not working.

Comment: Where are you loading each of the FXML files for which these are the controllers?

Comment: @HypnicJerk the method has to be in that class. The main controller contains the table I need to filter. The other class contains the method to look up the product (filter).

Comment: @James_D The FXML loaders are in the MainController class. They load other controllers as needed on events. So, the search input and the table are specified in the MainController class. From there, as you see above, I have an event to send the search String to the ContainsMethod class (for example), which, if you look further above, if where I'm trying to filter the table. No new controllers are being called, or stages opened / switched.

Comment: I don't see anything in the `lookUpProduct` method that HAS to be in that class. It creates a new `FilteredList` using `mainController` and then continues to use `mainController` throughout the rest of the method. Nothing in that method ever reaches in to `Inventory` and grabs something that is not available in `MainController`. Even in your invocation, you create a new `Inventory`, do not assign anything to it, although I can't see the constructor, but using the information in `lookUpProduct`, you aren't using any variable other than `mainController`

Comment: @HypnicJerk Thank you! I just was able to figure it out. I will post what my changes as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I had to do a few things differently:

**Inventory.java**

```
private MainController main;
@FXML private TableView<Product> productTableView;

public void setProductTableView(TableView<Product> main){
    this.productTableView = main;
}
public void setMainView(MainController main){ this.main = main; }

 void lookupProduct(String name){
    FilteredList<Product> filteredList = new FilteredList<Product>(productTableView.getItems());
    filteredList.stream()
            .filter(item -> item.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            .findAny()
            .ifPresent(item -> {
                productTableView.getSelectionModel().select(item);
                productTableView.scrollTo(item);
            });
    main.productsTableView.setItems(filteredList);
}
```

**MainController.java**

```
@FXML
private void handleLookupProduct(ActionEvent event) {
    Inventory inv = new Inventory();

    String searchText = productsSearchInput.getText();
    if (searchText.length() != 0) {

        inv.setMainView(this);
        inv.setProductTableView(productsTableView);
        inv.lookupProduct(searchText);
    } else {
        AlertBox.display("WAIT!", "Please enter a value to search!", 450);
    }
}
```

I had to create a method in **Inventory.java** to set MainController instance, then had to send the TableView to **Inventory.java** to allow me to get all the items from the TableView. Which then allowed me filter those results.

With the MainController instance set in Inventory, I was then able to set the FilteredList items on the table in the **MainController**